# Finding all the solutions of $\cos2\theta -\cos4\theta =0$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

$$\cos2\theta -\cos4\theta =0 $$  in the interval $[0,2\pi)$

So I know that I can use the Double or Half Angle formulas to simplify this and help me find the solutions. So I used the Double Angle Formulas and got:

$$2\cos^{ 2 }\theta -1-2\cos^{ 2 }2\theta -1=0$$

Now things get hairy with this value and I don't know how to go about solving from here.
$$2\cos^{ 2 }2\theta -1$$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use half angle formula only for $\cos 4\theta$ so that you get a quadratic equation in $\cos 2\theta$.

$$2\cos^2 2\theta - \cos 2\theta -1 = 0$$

Solve the equation for $\cos 2\theta$ and then for $\theta$.

Comment: So now I know that $cos2\theta =-\frac { 1 }{ 2 } ,\quad cos2\theta =1$
and $2\theta =\frac { 2\pi  }{ 3 } ,\quad \frac { 4\pi  }{ 3 } ,\quad 0$

Comment: So when is $\cos x = \frac{-1}{2}$ or $\cos x = 1$ in the interval $[0, 2\pi)$ ?

Comment: Well I know what $2\theta$ is, don't I have to divide those values by $2$?

Comment: Yes. You got it :)

Comment: So the solutions must be $\frac { \pi  }{ 3 } ,\quad \frac { 2\pi  }{ 3 } ,\quad 0$

Answer (score 3):

Hint:

$$0=\cos2\theta-\cos4\theta=\cos2\theta-2\cos^22\theta+1$$

Now solve the almost trivial quadratic.

Answer (score 3):

Whenever you have $\cos A=\cos B,$ we can safely say $A=2n\pi\pm B$  where $n$ is any integer

$$\cos4\theta=\cos2\theta \implies4\theta=2m\pi\pm2\theta$$ where $m$ is any integer

Taking the '-' sign, $\theta=\dfrac{m\pi}3\  \ \ \ (1)$

Taking the '+' sign, $\theta=m\pi$ which is a proper subset of $(1)$

Now we need $0\le \dfrac{m\pi}3<2\pi\iff 0\le m<6$

Comment: short and sweet

Answer (score 0):

$cos4\theta=2cos^22\theta-1=2(2cos\theta-1)^2-1=2(4cos^2\theta+1-4cos\theta)-1$

The original equation will then become

$8cos^2\theta+2-8cos\theta-1-2cos^2\theta+1=0$

$6cos^2\theta-8cos\theta+2=0$

$6cos\theta(cos\theta-1)-2(cos\theta-1)=0$

So,

$cos\theta=\frac{1}{3}$

Or,

$cos\theta=\frac{1}{2}$

:)

Answer (score 0):

$$\cos^2{\theta}-\sin^2\theta=2\cos2\theta-1$$

$$\cos^2\theta-\sin^2\theta=2\cos^2\theta-2\sin^2\theta -1$$

$$3\sin^2\theta=\cos^2\theta-1$$

$$3\sin^2\theta=sin^2\theta$$

$$2\sin^2\theta=0$$

or $\sin^2\theta=0$

$$\implies \theta=0$$

Therefore general solution is $\theta=n\pi$

Comment: Use mathjax  to write question